# Arquillian drone graphene Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary / chrome

Tags: jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

Arquillian - Drone - graphene - Glassfish- Firefox v.48 Chrome v.52.0.2743.116

Any help is appreciated

When i run my test it opens up the browser does not do any thing and i get following error

```
INFO: login was successfully deployed in 11,310 milliseconds.
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
lState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"/var/folders/wc/2w9f8xn95zs4r2ym8qbfrx1m0000gn/T/anonymous3674174231990276982webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1473864800000,"mt":1473864800000}},"app-system-defaults":{"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.1","st":1473864759000},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0.4","st":1473864759000},"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.4.4","st":1473864759000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"48.0.2","st":1473864759000}}}
1473864807843   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found

ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate Drone via org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(Capabilities): org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin) on port 7055; process output follows: 
lState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"/var/folders/wc/2w9f8xn95zs4r2ym8qbfrx1m0000gn/T/anonymous3674174231990276982webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1473864800000,"mt":1473864800000}},"app-system-defaults":{"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.1","st":1473864759000},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0.4","st":1473864759000},"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.4.4","st":1473864759000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"48.0.2","st":1473864759000}}}
1473864807843   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
```

Following is my test

```
package com.ex;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.RunAsClient;
import org.jboss.arquillian.drone.api.annotation.Drone;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.arquillian.spring.integration.test.annotation.SpringConfiguration;
import org.jboss.arquillian.test.api.ArquillianResource;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by FaisalKhan on 9/8/16.
 */

    @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    @SpringConfiguration("applicationContext.xml")
    @RunAsClient
    public class ArquillianTest {

        @Deployment
        public static Archive createTestArchive() {
            return Deployments.createDeployment();
        }

        @Drone
        private WebDriver browser;

        @ArquillianResource
        private URL contextRoot;

        @Before
        public void loadPage() {

            browser.navigate().to(contextRoot + "login");
        }

        @FindBy(id = "name")
        private WebElement loginInput;

        @FindBy(id = "pwd")
        private WebElement pwdInput;


        @FindBy(id = "submit")
        private WebElement submitBtn;



        @Test
        public void test_drone_Login() {
            loginInput.sendKeys("test");
            pwdInput.sendKeys("test");
            submitBtn.submit();
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

following is my arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
  http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

  <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"/>

  <extension qualifier="webdriver">
    <property name="browser">firefox</property>
  </extension>
</arquillian>
```

following is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.concretepage.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-testing</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>SpringMVC</name>


  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${maven.version}</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <repositories>

  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <arquillian.version>1.1.11.Final</arquillian.version>
    <jetty.distro.version>9.3.0.M1</jetty.distro.version>
    <maven.version>3.3.9</maven.version>
    <shrinkwrap.resolver.version>2.2.4</shrinkwrap.resolver.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.17.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <surefire.reportFormat>plain</surefire.reportFormat>
    <surefire.useFile>false</surefire.useFile>
    <surefire.version>2.19.1</surefire.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
          </exclusion>

          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
          </exclusion>

          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
          </exclusion>


          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.arquillian.universe</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
        <version>${shrinkwrap.resolver.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <profiles>

    <profile>
      <id>glassfish-embedded</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
          <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2.2</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>


  </profiles>
  <dependencies>

    <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
    </dependency>
-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-core</artifactId>
      <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-service-integration-spring-inject</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-container-test-impl-base</artifactId>
      <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
      <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
      <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
          <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
              <directory>src/main/webapp/</directory>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
          </webApp>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and following is my dependency tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ spring-mvc-testing ---
[INFO] com.concretepage.app:spring-mvc-testing:war:1.0.0
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-service-integration-spring-inject:jar:1.1.0.Alpha1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-api:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-connector-basic:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-transport-wagon:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-service-integration-spring:jar:1.1.0.Alpha1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.0-b01:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.graphene:graphene-webdriver:pom:2.1.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.graphene:graphene-webdriver-api:jar:2.1.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.graphene:graphene-webdriver-spi:jar:2.1.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.graphene:graphene-webdriver-impl:jar:2.1.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-impl:jar:2.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-configuration:jar:2.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain:pom:2.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-api:jar:2.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-spi:jar:2.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-webdriver:jar:2.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:jar:2.20:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.20:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.17:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.22:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.18:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.15.v20160210:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.15.v20160210:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.15.v20160210:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.15.v20160210:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.15.v20160210:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.opera:operadriver:jar:1.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.opera:operalaunchers:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ini4j:ini4j:jar:0.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-phantom-driver:jar:1.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |     +- com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain:pom:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  |        +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-archive:jar:2.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive:jar:2.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |           +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-archive:jar:2.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |           +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.0.M1:test
[INFO] |  |           |  \- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.0.M1:test
[INFO] |  |           \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |              \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.5.7.Final:test
[INFO] |     \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-leg-rc:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] \- org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.1.11.Final:compile
[INFO]    \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0-alpha-8:compile
```

Comment: Reading this horrible soup my only thought is "oh, dear God, can you please make people stop creating hordes of programming languages, libraries, APIs etc and focus them on perfecting a few".

Comment: haha i agree, its arquillian soup

Comment: I'm really curious what is the soup here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Related: [Receiving error: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary on port 7055](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42229783/55075)

Answer (score 2):

In Drone 2.0.1.Final (released today morning - in maven central probably tomorrow), there has been added a possibility to define your own firefox driver binary to support ff48 and associated gecko driver.

The gecko drivers can be downloaded here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

To define your gecko driver use the parameter "firefoxDriverBinary":

`<property name="firefoxDriverBinary">/path/to/your/driver/binary</property>`

For more information see: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-drone/commit/98843a2923acf201edb02738ba1113ec1ad74b32

To get this firefox version run, you need to have the latest selenium (3.0.0-beta3) on your classpath. As this is still a beta version and the release of Drone is a minor release, the version is nut fully supported yet - in other words, this version of selenium dependency is not automatically fetched (there is still 2.53.1). Please update your selenium-bom to the latest version and try it again.

Comment: I am glad that you are on SO. I feel that Graphene/Drone is not noticed properly. Answering questions on SO will help develop the community.

Answer (score 0):

For firefox, From v47, You need to use Marionette driver.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver/status

I am not sure if arquillian drone has been updated for this driver as it still seems to have issues. You need to downgrade firefox to v45 to run your tests.

For chrome, you need to set the path in the arquillian xml.

```
 <extension qualifier="webdriver">
    <property name="browser">chrome</property>
    <property name="chromeDriverBinary">path</property>
  </extension>
```

Check here for the maven dependencies and other info:

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automation-using-arquillian-framework/